# JNI Error on Scene Transition Animation - Layer exceeds max

Tags: android, android-animation, picasso

**please notice the EDIT in the bottom of the question**

I have 2 activities: `ActivityA`, `ActivityB` with associated frgments: `FragmentA`, `FragmentB`  respectively. `ImageView v` is shared between those two fragments.

some Code: *ActivityA*

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
final ActivityOptionsCompat activityOptionsCompat = ActivityOptionsCompat.
                         makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this, imageView, "photo");   

ActivityCompat.startActivity(this, intent, activityOptionsCompat.toBundle());
```

*ActivityB*

```
FragmentB fragment = new FragmentB();
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()..replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, TAG).addToBackStack(TAG).commit();
```

*FragmentB*

```
mView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.view);
ViewCompat.setTransitionName(mView, "photo);
```

4 out of 5 times it's working. but when it's not working i'm getting the **Very informative** error:

```
W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Layer exceeds max. dimensions supported by the GPU (1080x10659, max=4096x4096)
JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI CallVoidMethodV called with pending exception 'java.lang.IllegalStateException' thrown in void android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(long, int):-2
```

Call to `Picasso`

```
Picasso.with(context).load(url).centerCrop().resize(width, height).noFade().into(mView);
```

*Few things that can cause this:*

1. in `FragmentB` `mView` position is calculated dynamically using `ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener`
2. `mView` extends `ImageView` in order to create Oval effect in both of the Fragments.
3. the root `ViewGroup` is a `ScrollView`

one last thing: the `Theme` of both of the activities is a child of

```
<style name="Theme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light"
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowReturnTransitionOverlap">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementExitTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
</style>
```

**--- EDIT ---**

[Similar question and answer to my problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26664922/crash-material-design-android-5-0/27906489)
[and another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26626344/scene-transition-with-hero-elements-throws-layer-exceeds-max-dimensions-support)

Answer do solve the issue but only for *API 21*. I'm using `ActivityCompat.startActivity(...)`. it supports *api 16* and above **but** `TransitionListener` is only available since *API 19* and supports `SceneTransition` since *API 21*

Also `android:transitionGroup="true"` requires `API 21` so now i have **2 main questions:**

1. Why i'm even getting `LayerExceeds max` error? my shared `View` is no bigger than 1080x1080.
2. how can i handle this kind of error on *API < 21* where both `TransitionListener` and `transitionGroup` are unavailable?

**ERROR stacktrace**

```
JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI CallVoidMethodV called with pending exception 'java.lang.IllegalStateException' thrown in void android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(long, int):-2
in call to CallVoidMethodV
art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65] from void android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(long, int)
art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65] "main" prio=5 tid=1 Runnable
art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x72fb6000 self=0xb4827800
art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   | sysTid=6497 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xb6f83bec
art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   | state=R schedstat=( 1181860917 459124594 2277 ) utm=100 stm=18 core=2 HZ=100
art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   | stack=0xbe27d000-0xbe27f000 stackSize=8MB
art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #00 pc 00004e64  /system/lib/libbacktrace_libc++.so (UnwindCurrent::Unwind(unsigned int, ucontext*)+23)
art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #01 pc 00003665  /system/lib/libbacktrace_libc++.so (Backtrace::Unwind(unsigned int, ucontext*)+8)
art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #02 pc 00256429  /system/lib/libart.so (art::DumpNativeStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, int, char const*, art::mirror::ArtMethod*)+84)
art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #03 pc 00238fe7  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) const+158)
art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #04 pc 000b191b  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JniAbort(char const*, char const*)+610)
art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #05 pc 000b2055  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JniAbortF(char const*, char const*, ...)+68)
art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #06 pc 000b530f  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ScopedCheck::ScopedCheck(_JNIEnv*, int, char const*)+1346)
art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #07 pc 000bd6f7  /system/lib/libart.so (art::CheckJNI::CallVoidMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+42)
art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #08 pc 0006244b  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (???)
art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #09 pc 000760c5  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::NativeDisplayEventReceiver::dispatchVsync(long long, int, unsigned int)+40)
native: #10 pc 0007628d  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::NativeDisplayEventReceiver::handleEvent(int, int, void*)+80)
native: #11 pc 00012545  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollInner(int)+484)
native: #12 pc 000125ed  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollOnce(int, int*, int*, void**)+92)
native: #13 pc 00081709  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::NativeMessageQueue::pollOnce(_JNIEnv*, int)+22)
native: #14 pc 000b3863  /data/dalvik-cache/arm/system@framework@boot.oat (Java_android_os_MessageQueue_nativePollOnce__JI+102)
at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native method)
at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:143)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:122)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(Native method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xfffffff0 in tid 6497
```

Comment: possibly related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26664922/crash-material-design-android-5-0

Comment: That's a warning, not an error.  If you think there is an error that results, post a more complete log output starting earlier and continuing to show how this results in termination or other serious failure.

Comment: If you are able to reproduce this on an emulator, on a Nexus device, or on devices from multiple manufacturers, it probably represents an Android OS bug. In that case, if you can publish a project that reproduces the error, please [file an issue](http://b.android.com). I have not yet played with activity transitions and I haven't the foggiest notion of how to work around it, but a native crash from Java code means a firmware problem in most cases. The only variable is whether this is the fault of some manufacturer or Android proper.

Answer (score 2):

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26638729/15882) to the second question you linked discusses the reason this happens: the size limit is on the entire prerendered target Activity, not just the transitioned element(s). Adding `android:transitionGroup="true"` to the appropriate place in the transitioned layout will fix the crash. You didn't post your layout in the question so it's hard to know where that would go, but if you have a `ScrollView` or other very long view that would be a good place to start.

For API levels before 21, this is a non-issue. `AppCompat.startActivity()` will work on API levels below 21, but the shared element transition animation will not run. It will fall back to the default activity transition.