# Android M: Scene transition with hero elements throws java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have a scene transition that I had some issues with:
[Scene transition with hero elements throws Layer exceeds max. dimensions supported by the GPU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26626344/scene-transition-with-hero-elements-throws-layer-exceeds-max-dimensions-support)

But setting transitionGroup fixed it. When I compile the exact same app with the the latest Android M SDK it crashes when pressing back from the transition.

```
Abort message: 'art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: 
JNI CallObjectMethod called with pending exception java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Unable to create layer for RelativeLayout'
```

Anyone knows if Google changed anything regarding this in Android M?

It is reported here: 
https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=2416

But no resolution...