# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to create layer for v

Tags: java, android, exception, android-view, android-5.0-lollipop

I have this exception on crashlytics and have no idea how to reproduce or what the cause might be. Does anyone have any pointers as to where I should start looking? Only affects Android 5+.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to create layer for v
       at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(MessageQueue.java)
       at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:323)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5585)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
```

Thanks.

Edit: I would like to update that it doesn't only affect Android 5, it seems to affect Android 5+

Comment: Are you developing a native app or other platforms like Xamarin?

Comment: Normal Android with Java.

Comment: I assume you have some kind of comprehension as to where this happens. Copy-paste the code and layout for the relevant activity into your question

Comment: I don't really know where it happens because the crash report from Crashlytics doesn't give me any more information and it has never happened to me and no user has ever reported it.  That being said, this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/43853650/704836 might be onto something as I do use `makeSceneTransitionAnimation` once in my code for a very simple `ImageView`. Since I don't know of any users experiencing the issue, it is a bit hard to test it.

Comment: This happens mostly with FireOS devices. No idea why.

Answer (score 11):

This issue seems related to [Scene transition with hero elements throws Layer exceeds max. dimensions supported by the GPU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26626344/scene-transition-with-hero-elements-throws-layer-exceeds-max-dimensions-support).

You should look at any activity transaction you are making and particularly for the effects of `makeSceneTransitionAnimation()`.

Comment: I do have one call to `makeSceneTransitionAnimation` in which I pass a simple `ImageView`. Thanks for link.

Comment: @casolorz Did it stop the crashes? Can you share your experience?

Comment: This specific crash has gone away over time (this question is from 2017) but I don't remember if it was because of that `makeSceneTransitionAnimation` or if it just went away on its own with time.

Answer (score 7):

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to create layer for LinearLayout, size 1080x4160 exceeds max size 4096
       at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(MessageQueue.java)
       at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:323)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6186)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
```

I have same issue for RecyclerView inside NestedScrollView

RecyclerView <- inside NestedScrollView

**Solution:**
As RecyclerView inside scrollview or nestedscrollview try to load all items at once. As RecyclerView loads all items at once, also loads items that are not visible right now on screen. If you put log inside onBindViewHolder of RecylerView you find that all items loads at the start instead of based on the visibility of the item.

This causes UI to load more than 1-1.5 screens of content at a time. This causes the parent LinearLayout (inside the ScrollView) to throw exception. It's suggested to paginate your content and load no more than 1-1.5 screens of content at a time. [I had also issue related to same with Recyclerview without animation](https://android--kotlin.blogspot.com/2019/07/android-java-lang-illegalstateexception-unable-to-create-layer-for-linearlayout.html).

Answer (score 3):

adding `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"` to `application` tag in `manifest` solve my problem

EDIT: 
please see comment by @inteist

Comment: this is not a good solution. It makes everything super jagged and slow. No reason to punish everyone because Samsun and LG screwed up a few of their models.

Answer (score 2):

I also faced this issue when I tried to create a simple View. I just had to set `android:forceHasOverlappingRendering="false"` in its xml. Note that it only works from API level 24.

Comment: But where do I put that? I don't even know what activity it is happening under.

Comment: Yes, it's hard to find because log doesn't contain any information about that view element. I suggest you go through your app screen by screen and try to figure out which activity/fragment contains that view because the app is going to crash when it tries to render it.
Another way is using `git bisect` if you source controlled your project with git. First you have to find a previous commit when it worked, then you can find the commit - which contains the buggy part - with _bisect_. Here you can find more information about how to use _bisect_: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was a **silly mistake** and Android Studio didn't show any warning.

I had a view set with the id of `@+id/myView` yet I had also set in the same view/tag `android:layout_below=@id/myView`.

Something like this:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_below="@id/textview" /> <!-- The traitor :( -->
```