# Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException - Unable to create layer for LinearLayout(Crashing in only Galaxy j4+, j6+)

Tags: java, android, crash, google-fabric, galaxy

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException Unable to create
>   layer for LinearLayout, size 768x5440 max size 8192 color type 4 has
>   context 1

```
android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce (MessageQueue.java)
android.os.Looper.loop + 181 (Looper.java:181)
android.app.ActivityThread.main + 7097 (ActivityThread.java:7097)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main + 975 (ZygoteInit.java:975)
```

I received a nativePollOnce.java crash alarm from the firebase Crashlytics, but only a few of the many (galaxy j4 +, j6 +) models will crash frequently. How did i resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43748222/java-lang-illegalstateexception-unable-to-create-layer-for-v?answertab=votes#tab-top) is related - the first answer in that link that links to [Scene transition with hero elements throws Layer exceeds max. dimensions supported by the GPU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26626344/scene-transition-with-hero-elements-throws-layer-exceeds-max-dimensions-support) might help you.

Answer (score 2):

I had this error and bought a samsung J4 device to solve it.
In my case there was a screen with many recyclerviews and nestedscrollviews.
The solution was to remove "match_parent" and manually set the size (height or widht) of one of the recyclerviews. I think this somehow made the calculations of the GPU easier.